# NextJS with ant design, msal Jest setup problem (Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: next.js, jestjs, antd, ts-jest

I'm new to Jest setup, I've setup Jest based on nextjs with Jest example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest

here is my jest.config.js

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@azure/msal-react|antd)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@azure/msal-react': '<rootDir>/mocked/module.js',
  },
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    // these options are overrides used only by ts-node
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@/public": ["public/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and here is a Jest to check if the test can run successfully

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Button } from 'antd';

jest.mock('next/navigation', () => ({
  useRouter: () => ({
    route: '/',
    pathname: '/',
    query: {},
    asPath: '/',
  }),
  usePathname: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Login', () => {
  it('render page', () => {
    render(<Button />);
    const heading = 'render';
    expect(heading).toEqual('render');
  });
});
```

when I run the test, I got this error

> \node_modules\antd\es\button\index.js:3
> import Button from './button';
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I'm currently using NextJS 14.0.3, next-intl, redux tool kit, antd 5.11.2

The test run normally without library component so I don't know if I missed anything else

I hope someone can help me with this, appreciate a lot

I have tried to config and researched to solve the issue but no luck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so I solve my issue here in this post, hope this helps anyone out there and me in the future

so basically, NextJS got an example in its github, I've followed it and if you only need to test with built-in element in NextJS (no other library), follow the example can help you setup Jest without further config, you can have a look at this [NextJS with jest example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest)

In my case, my project including UI library, redux tool kit, next-intl... so I did some research and end up with this
[setup jest in NextJS 14 with msal, redux tool kit](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/58994), I've included all the code in this post link, there is still some things I don't understand so appreciate it if anyone could explain but now, the config work well

*edit: it seems like this part is not need

```
transpilePackages: [
    "antd",
    "rc-util",
    "@babel/runtime",
    "@ant-design/icons",
    "@ant-design/icons-svg",
    "rc-pagination",
    "rc-picker",
    "rc-tree",
    "rc-table",
  ],
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Jesse oh thanks for your suggestion, I'll try my best to provide more information